# Trying to make the next and previous button appear at different times of the registration form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to make my registration form for my site and I am doing a next and previous to go through my site, I have the next and previous working well but I want the previous button to hide when I am on the first question and the registration sign to show when I am on the last question.

Here is my JS

```
      var nameRegistration = document.querySelector('.name- 
      registration');
      var emailRegistration = document.querySelector('.email- 
      registration');
      var industriesRegistration = document.querySelector('.industries- 
      registration');
      var birthRegistration = document.querySelector('.birth- 
      registration');
      var passwordRegistration = document.querySelector('.password-registration');

var nextContainer = document.querySelector('#forward');
var backContainer = document.querySelector('#back');
var registerContainer = document.querySelector('#register-btn-container');

  if (nameRegistration.style.display === 'none ') {
    backContainer.style.display = 'block'
} 

  if (passwordRegistration.style.display === 'block') {
    registerContainer.style.display = 'block'
}
```

Comment: W3schools has a good example of this here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in many ways, for example keep a counter to know in wich part of the process you are, and keep incremeting and decreasing on each "section" change and act accordingly to that.

The checkSection edit to what options/fields you will need.

```
let activeSection = 0;

const checkSection = position => {
//if not in the start, hide start section/button/option
 if(position == 0) {
   document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('otherid').style.display = 'block';
}
 else { 
  document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('otherid').style.display = 'block';
  } 
}

//and control where you are with listeners to the clicks
document.getElementById('linkmoveup').addEventListener('click',function(e){
   //don't follow link
   e.preventDefault();
   //lets assume this is for the next point, increment position counter
   activeSection++;
   //recheck for what is active
   checkSection(activeSection);
});
```

Comment: But how do I implement that with the code I have now

Comment: let i = 0;

    function nextSeg() {
        i = i + 1 
        a = i - 1;
        registerItem[i].style.display = 'block';
        registerItem[a].style.display = 'none';
    }

Comment: @JafferSyed depends...

if you only want to appear when i == 0 just make the if with position > 0 and change accordingly.
the id/other id is what you want to show/hide.

can create the case when i == last, to show, inside the checksection.

or using your nextSeg make a condition to check if i=0 -> show next, if i == max, show x.